# How to get trace when Android phone crashes while developing in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I upgraded a 2013 Nexus 4 to Android 5.1, and I am using it to develop a react-native Android app with a https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner, using the Navigator component for navigation.

Here is my react version

```
"react": "15.0.2",
"react-native": "0.26.1",
"react-native-barcodescanner": "2.0.0"
```

After an initial deploy of react-native run-android, I would typically run during development:

```
adb  -d reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
react-native start
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

I would rage shake the phone to Reload JS every time I update my index.android.js (only file I am changing).  The app would crash the phone time to time (screen goes black, I have to long press power button to restart).   I would say this happens maybe every 15 minutes, whether I am scanning something or not, and sometimes right after I reload JS.  My phone never crashes otherwise running any other apps.

**Question:**

In my window adb logcat, there is zero indication of what went wrong  when my phone crashes.  What are the toolsets available in react-native/Android development to help trace the error for the crash?  Back when I worked with Windows CE, if we have a kernel debugger attached via Visual Studio, then an exception raised would trigger a debugger break with full callstack and you can debug the cause of the device crash on the spot.  If the device runs out of memory, there will be a lot of debug print outs as well.  Is there something similar?  Thanks.